# AngularJS Directive $scope is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following directive. When I trigger the `open` function and get to the debugger I get an error message in the console that says `Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined(…)`.

How is it possible for `$scope.open` to be called when `$scope` is undefined?

```
app.directive('photo', ['$http', 'modal', function($http, modal) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/assets/photo.html',
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            result: '=',
            index: '@'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', 'modal', function($scope, $http, modal) {
            $scope.prev = $scope.index - 1;
            $scope.open = function() {
                debugger;
            };
        }]
    }
}]);
```

Here is my DOM:

```
<div ng-repeat="r in results" photo result="r" index="$index"></div>
```

If I insert `console.log($scope)` just before my `open` function, and then again right before the `debugger` in that function, I get the following results. Left is before `open` is called, right is after `open` is called. 
[image]

Comment: What do you see when you add this line before ```debugger;``` ```console.log($scope);```.  This may be important because the compiler may be optimizing your $scope variable away when you're inside of $scope.open.

Comment: I just updated my question with a screenshot. Note that `temp1 != temp2`.

Comment: `$id` shouldn't  be a string. The AngularJS framework uses numbers for scope `$id`. Something outside Angular is messing with that reserved variable.

Answer (score 3):

You inject the `$http` and `modal` in the directive definition (as you did), no need to in the controller function, just do:

```
controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.prev = $scope.index - 1;
        $scope.open = function() {
            debugger;
        };
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so this solves the problem, but what I'd like to know is why? I have used the same dependency injection format for many other directives without any issues. Why would this one be different?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really know the reason for that :(

Comment: His syntax to inject $scope should work just fine.  Check out "Creating Directives that Communicate" in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: @StevenWexler - Thank you, I will look into that

Comment: I wonder if it's somehow affected by `ng-repeat`, but that strikes me as strange, since most of my directives are attached to repeaters just like the snippet in my question.

Comment: ACIDSTEALTH - Have you tried @RahulTagore's answer? Perhaps you also needed to include $scope in the dependencies list of your directive?

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. It gives an injector error. Your solution doesn't seem to be working either. I thought it was working before but then it stopped and I can't get it back again.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a statement that uses `$scope` in `$scope.open`.  Chrome has probably optimized `$scope` away when you're in `$scope.open` because you're not using it.

```
$scope.open = function() {
  console.log($scope);
  debugger; //now you should see $scope.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

its worked for me

```
var app = angular.module("moduleTest",[]);
app.directive("testDirective",function(){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element){
           //code
           //and $scope is scope
        }
    }   
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
app.directive('photo', ['$http', 'modal', function($http, modal) {
return {
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/assets/photo.html',
    transclude: false,
    scope: {
        result: '=',
        index: '@'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $http, modal) {
        $scope.prev = $scope.index - 1;
        $scope.open = function() {
            debugger;
        };
    }
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the $Scope at the top i.e.:
        app.directive('photo', ['$http', '$Scope','modal', function($http, $Scope,        modal)

It will work fine now.

Comment: You don't inject `$scope` into a directive like that. My dependency injection is correct. I know because I have dozens of other directives following the same format that work great.